# Generating a list of angular bundles for export

Tags: angular

I am attempting to generate a list of the bundles generated by the angular production build process (with output hashing) so that I can then include those filenames on a server generated output (a Laravel blade view).

I've had a look at the stats.json file, but the end result is large and not suitable for a deployment script.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: why not just list the js files in the dist folder?

Comment: Thanks, @SureshNagar, that's what I went with. I just wasn't sure if there was a simple command line option I was missing.